# why applications tab don't appear on tizen seller office anymore?

Tags: tizen

Applications tab and add new apps don't appear on tizen seller office. I am using brave as my default browser.

Documentation website:

[image]

Screenshot of my tizen seller office dashboard:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide your code.

Comment: i dont ask about code im asking about tizen office seller dashboard(applications and add application tabs dont appear)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

doesnt matter anymore tizen services will be deprecated